# Server Error on placing order via Braintree Paypal during guest checkout

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, magento-2.1.3, guest-checkout

I am getting following exception on guest checkout via Braintree. I am using Paypal Sandbox for testing.

Anyone know why I am getting this error.

```
An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.exception 'Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandException' with message 'Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.' in C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-payment\Gateway\Command\GatewayCommand.php:101
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\Adapter.php(530): Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\GatewayCommand->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Method\Adapter.php(433): Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter->executeCommand('authorize', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\AuthorizeOperation.php(45): Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter->authorize(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), 50)
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor.php(72): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Operations\AuthorizeOperation->authorize(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), true, 50)
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment.php(1054): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor->authorize(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor), true, 50)
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor.php(427): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->authorize(true, 50)
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment.php(421): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->authorize(true, 50)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Payment.php(348): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->processAction('authorize', Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order))
#8 C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor.php(167): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment->place()
#9 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order.php(871): Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor->place()
#10 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order.php(1060): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->_placePayment()
#11 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Service\OrderService.php(190): Magento\Sales\Model\Order->place()
#12 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\QuoteManagement.php(489): Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService->place(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order))
#13 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\QuoteManagement.php(391): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote), Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\QuoteManagement.php(349): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote))
#15 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement.php(87): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->placeOrder('78', NULL)
#16 C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement\Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement->placeOrder('9980700107cfb16...', NULL)
#17 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(81): Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartManagement\Interceptor->placeOrder('9980700107cfb16...')
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('9980700107cfb16...', 'fgdgdfg@fdfsd.c...', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))
#19 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(307): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#21 C:\wamp\www\magento\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#24 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#25 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue. It occurred because the Dynamic Descriptor text I used in the Magento Admin Configuration -> Sales -> Payment -> Braintree was incorrect.

The Company name should be 3,7 or 12 characters long and the product name should be 14,18 or 9 characters long. And most important there must be a " * " between both texts.

Eg: CMD*Membershipfees

The Maximum length of the final descriptor is 22. Hope this will help someone facing a similar issue.